# Intermittent "Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent" error when downloading files via api call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download, asp.net-apicontroller

The file has been successfully downloaded and show the images in the ui. However I'm getting an exception error "**Exception Message: Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent. Stack Trace:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value)**" in the logs. Sorry, this might be a duplicate question but it is still happening on my end with all the possible fixes I found online.

Note: Api call multiple times on a single page.

Here's the example code:

```
// send file to client
byte[] bytes = result.Image; - image bytes
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent(); 
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Buffer = true;

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString()); 
Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";

Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();

return Json(new { success = true, Message = "Image Successfully Render" }, "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: The error message is very clear.  The server sent the response to client so you cannot modify the response after it was sent.  There must be another part of your code that already sent the response.  Possibly there was an error processing the request and the error sent the response and now your code is still processing after the error occurred.

Comment: @jdweng, is there a way to handle that kind of behaviour? And also, for this statement "There must be another part of your code that already sent the response." does it mean response from other api calls?

Comment: You have a controller that is processing the request and sending responses.  So you can have error handlers and routes.  Other api calls would be a different route.  Code "should" only process one route with every request.  Your processing code should all be withing a route.  If you have code outside a route it could be the reason for the issue.